# azure 502 bad gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

has anyone seen this before so I am getting a 502 bad gateway error on my app, the issue I have is that the detailed error information I am getting says my requested url is https://SOX:80/api however my site is configured to use https://sox.domain.com and the site largely works pulling the various JS files required

my app service name is SOX in the azure dashboard so I assume that is where it is picking up SOX from but I have no idea why it is using this.

Comment: Can we see the detailed error information? Currently, we don't have much to go on to help you.

Answer (score 1):

So overall the issue had me perplexed... however with more testing I soon figured out what was going on.

my backend is Dotnet core Azure throwing the 502 bad gateway was its way of handling exceptions ultimately the problem was code based.
I am mentioning this purely so that it will help others

my first issue was based on cert handling it seems dotnet runs in a container that is specified by your app name as i mentioned above  https://SOX:80

the below was causing my issues

sslPolicyErrors = X509StoreStoreHelper.ValidateSSLPolicy(cert.Thumbprint, cert);

after commenting this out for testing my problem went away(we are putting in a proper fix )

my second issue came from using an unsupported view in Azure SQL master.sys.master_files which again just threw a 502 bad gateway error referencing  https://SOX:80

please note I have used  https://SOX:80 as a reference to mask the real site.

hope this helps the next person.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I have checked your site (`https://sox.azurewebsites.net/`) and found that it contains three static files (`index.html`,`generic.html`,`elements.html`). I viewed your website in Chrome incognito window as follows:

[image]

I did not find any requests against `https://SOX:80/api` in your html page or JavaScript files. Please try to access your website in a new incognito window to isolate the cache issue or just press CTRL + F5 to refresh your current page to narrow this issue. Moreover, you need to check whether you have configured [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). If you still could not solve this issue, you need to update your question with the details for us to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thanks Bruce i should have mentioned i used SOX as a place holder for the real name. I should have checked to make sure no one else was using it. i have found my issue and will be detailing it below